# How to test this async server response with Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, sinon

I want to write a Jasmine test for an async fetch call. This is how my test looks at the moment:

```
describe("async fetch call", function(){
        it ("should contact server and call callback success", function(){
            var server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
            server.autoRespond = true;
            server.respondWith([200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, '{"collection":"coll","response":"resp", "options":"opts", "readyState":"1"}']);
            var callback = {
                success: jasmine.createSpy("success").and.callFake(function (){
                    expect(callback.success).toHaveBeenCalled();
                }),
                error: jasmine.createSpy("error")
            };
            session.getCompanies(callback);
            server.restore();
        });
    });
```

The function session.getCompanies is calling the fetch command.
I use Jasmine 2.2.0 and SinonJS. When I run this test, expect is called too late. How can I make the test wait until expect was called?

Comment: Is this an integration test? Why dont you replace the async server with a stub and trigger a synchronous response in your test case?

Comment: I need to use the async way because I write this test for a thesis and thus have to show different procedures. If I would use a stub, would the test still be called an integration test?

Comment: I see. You probably want to use Jasmine's [done](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support) mechanism.

Comment: yes, but how does that work? I can't figure it out

Comment: I'd say you just need to include done as a parameter in the test case function, and call done() only in the async callback, not earlier. What did you try so far?

Comment: oh you are right... i read about this subject and found that jasmine does not support callbacks. but that was an earlier version. Since Version 2.0 `done()` is supported in `beforeEach()`, `afterEach()` and `it()`.

Comment: but what about my question in the second comment? if i use a stub as server and the call is only synchronous, would this still be called an integration test?